# Get rid of facebook shared/liked URL query (via mod_rewrite)

Tags: facebook, mod-rewrite, facebook-like

URLs from within facebook are shared like this:

```
www.mydomain.com
```

becomes

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?fb_action_ids=423308397714910&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%22423308397714910%22%3A10151847670865082%7D&action_type_map=%7B%22423308397714910%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D
```

No joke. This is - afaik - the standard behaviour of link sharing. Problem is: This query changes permanently. So the shared URL always starts with 0 likes.

My question is:
How to get rid of this ?

UPDATE: This happens only under special circumstances, like when mod_rewrites on your server that redirect http://lalala.com to http://www.lalala.com - this seems to irritate the facebook redirector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get rid of it, just make sure

1. Your `og:url` meta tag and / or canonical meta tag are pointing to the correct URL.
2. Your like buttons have the `href` defined and they're pointing to the correct URL (without those extraneous parameters).

If someone clicks a link from Facebook, and copy/pastes the URL (including the `fb_action_ids`,etc params) and shares it back to Facebook, Facebook's crawler will follow the `og:url` or canonical meta tag and fetch the tags from that URL, which won't have the referral parameters.

If someone clicks the link and ends up on your page and you're rendering a like button, provided you haven't ommitted the href parameter on the like button, the like count for the actual URL will be visible and the like button will be for whatever URL the `href` points to (which presumably will exclude the referral parameters)

Comment: Good answer, thank you, but what' the correct notation of the fb href attribute ? I'm very confused as there is `date-href=""` and `fb:like:href` and `href`. Beside that, i don't see the difference between hard-coding the current URL and the facebook-recognition.

Comment: I believe those three options are dependant on which version of the like plugin you're using - the value of that parameter should be the canonical URL of that page/site/content, stripping out any parameters which aren't needed by your site to render that content